# problem in handling menu - submenu based on spring security

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

I have configured spring security core plugin using requestmap table inside the database..

Now inside requestmap table I have all the possible urls and it's equivalent roles who can access that url...

Now I want to generate menus and submenus based on the urls stored in requestmap table...

So my requirement is to check the urls of menu & submenus against the logged in users privileges... And if logged in user has any one privilege then I need to display that main menu and the available submenus....

For e.g. I have a menu in my project called user which has a following submenus :

```
**Users (main menu)**
Manage Users (sub menu)
Import Users (sub menu)
```

Now inside my header.gsp I have successfully achieved the above requirement using if else condition, like :

```
if ( privs.contains("/users/manageUsers") || privs.contains("/users/importUsers"))
```

here privs are the list of urls from requestmap table for logged in user.

But I want to achieve these using spring security tag lib, so for comparing urls I have find following tag from spring security core documentation :

```
<sec:access url="/users/manageUsers">
```

But i am bit confuse that how I can replace or condition using tag library.. Is there any tag available which checks from multiple urls and evaluate it to true or false ?

Of course I can do using sec:access tag with some flag logic, but is there any tags available which can fulfill my requirement directly ?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<sec:access/>` tag has an `expression` attribute which will evaluate the expression you pass it:
http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/6%20Helper%20Classes.html#6.1%20SecurityTagLib

You could also very easily create your own [logical tag](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.3.3%20Logical%20Tags), which renders the tag body only if your privilege-checking conditional above is true.

Comment: thanks for your response... but also using expression tag how I can execute multiple url checking in a single expression ?